# Why does Walt become less strict about Walter Jr.'s driving style in Half Measures?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

It's not entirely clear why Walt has a completely different attitude about Walter Jr's driving style in the episode Half Measures, in which he basically says "as long it gets you from point A to point B" it's fine. Is he being more understanding of his son's disability or he just doesn't care as much anymore? Is this in some sense a "half measure" as well?

Comment: It's a metaphor about how Walt ceases to care about the means, so long as the end is what he wants. It marks Walt's further turn away from the moral, straight laced person he was and his movement towards becoming Heisenburg as a person, rather than a persona. Someone else is welcome to flesh this out with evidence from the show.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in season 2 episode 4 "Down"

[image]

Walt tells his son that he cannot use both feet to drive

> You can't use one foot on each pedal

Then in the episode you mention (3-12 "Half-measures"), when Walt notices that Jr is still using both feet, the son tells his father

> I looked it up. New Mexico says all I need is a note from a doctor

to what Walt responds "Well, as long as it gets you safely from point A to point B..." and then congratulates him

[image]

Walt understands that his son's disability doesn't allow him to drive like everyone else, and tends to acknowledge the driving particularity.